# Some users can't install app due to INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, dex

For almost a year now I've been receiving complaints from a fraction of my users that either can't install my app, or have it installed but could not update it later. I did my best to reproduce this bug so that I could have a lead on what might cause it, but the only thing users mentioned is that they get a -504 error code from Google Play. I did not manage to reproduce it.

Luckily, one of my friends who installed the app had this issue and I have his phone's logcat while the install was going on. I don't quite understand what is causing the bug.

Included are the [.apk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFPDzdfT0tqZmFzYUkxNnJZZTQ/view?usp=sharing) and the [logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFPDzdfT0tqVnFYLXVTc09ua0U/view?usp=sharing) output of the failed installation through Google Play.
I have added a few blank lines just before the relevant part towards the end. Be warned, there's a lot of trash to be sifted through, I didn't know what might be relevant so I tried my best to trim the edges only.

My package name is "com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator". Search for "INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT" to quickly find the relevant section.

I don't have multidexing in my app because my rough method count is about 30k.

app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24

    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 133
        versionName "1.77"
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/'] } }
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/exp4j-0.4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/EJML-simple-0.28.jar')
    compile files('libs/EJML-core-0.28.jar')
    compile files('libs/EJML-dense64-0.28.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

}

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: post errors, logs etc something which can actually help to find the problem

Comment: I posted the logcat of the installation, do you not see it?

Comment: In your logs I found;

Comment: According to your logs, ahead-of-time compilation failed because of memory violation in dex2oat process. To verify that, you can try [to disable the AOT compilation](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/disable-android-art-ahead-of-time-compilation-to-optimize-debug-deployment/), and see if you're able to install it on the problematic phone (in case you have access to it).

Comment: I will try it when I can get a faulty phone, this sounds like a very good lead. In any case, you should post this as an answer so I could accept it if this is indeed the case. Just a quick question: can I disable AOT compilation in release builds? I am not concerned with debug builds, and the article mentions that you shouldn't override this attribute in release builds.

Comment: I ran it through with one of my users and this was indeed the issue, disabling AOT enabled him to install. I would have never discovered this on my own. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. Also, my question still stands: what downsides are there to disabling AOT in release builds?

Comment: This should be fixed with AndroidStudio 3.1.3 now: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3-1-0

Answer (score 1):

I found in your logs

```
E/audit   ( 4121): type=1701 msg=audit(1479663260.831:639): auid=4294967295 uid=50210 gid=50210 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:dex2oat:s0 pid=28835 comm=436F6D70696C657220647269766572 reason="memory violation" sig=6
E/installd( 2585): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator-1/base.apk' --- status=0x0006, process failed
I/PackageManager( 3177): do mInstaller.dexopt : -1
D/PackageManager( 3177): Time to dexopt: 4.566 seconds
W/PackageManager( 3177): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator-1
W/PackageManager( 3177): com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: scanPackageLI
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageDirtyLI(PackageManagerService.java:7714)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:6916)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installNewPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:13233)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:14196)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2700(PackageManagerService.java:327)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$8.run(PackageManagerService.java:11346)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/PackageManager( 3177):        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
D/PackageManager( 3177): doPostInstall for uid{-1}
```

and later on the part which you mentioned:

```
D/PackageManager( 3177): result of install: -11{277491727}
E/Finsky  (28617): [1] com.google.android.finsky.installer.bs.onReceive(2631): Error -504 while installing com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator-1: scanPackageLI
W/Finsky  (28617): [1] com.google.android.finsky.installer.as.a(2324): Install failure of com.jjsoftware.fullscientificcalculator: -504 null
```

Let's verify this log with proper installation. Let's check on which Android it's working and on which it does not. 
Do you use **multidexing** in you project?

More about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: The error happens between Android 5.01 and 5.1. This I know. I don't use multidexing because I'm not close to the method limit in my app. Note that although the error occurs on those versions, it's rare even then.

Comment: if you can, please update your post with gradle config and dependency

Comment: @JohanZ. there is nothing strange in your configuration. Did you try to reproduce it on emulator with  Android 5.01 ~5.1 ? I will check PackageMangerService.java sources why this could happen.

Comment: Check also what size have your classes.dex inside apk. If this file is over 5MB it could be problematic. From older posts in SO simple targetSDK change helped some people.

Comment: I've tried all of that with no luck. I checked the classes.dex inside and it is 4.4MB large. I've ran the installation through all possible Android versions and the problem could not be reproduced. This is especially frustrating since it makes it hard tracking it down. The only reason I have this log is because I was lucky enough to have a friend with a version on which the app could not be installed.

Comment: I've also read that this problem might occur because of a faulty method with a lot of variables. If you scroll up in the log it mentions something about one of my methods "preCalculation()", lists the assembly lines and then mentions that it ran out of memory, which might lead to the failed install. I haven't had the chance to test this yet, but it might be the culprit. Worth checking out?

Comment: I think so. Do you have app on Play store ? I have many different phones with different androids I could try to reproduce it. Also did that happen on fresh install or update for new version ?

Comment: Certainly! It's called "Full Scientific Calculator".

Comment: It happens in both cases. Sometimes users can't install a new version and are stuck with an old one, and some users can't install it at all.

Comment: It installed without any problems of all android from 4.1 do 6. Could you share older version, to check what it behaves when update ?

Comment: As I told you before, even if you try to install it on the faulty versions it doesn't always lead to a failed installation -- that is why I couldn't reproduce this bug myself.

Comment: I tried few times now I cannot reproduce it. Probably it's connected with older or low lever memory devices.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this error by disabling new android dex compiler D8.

Just remove `android.enableD8=true` from ´gradle.properties´.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Android Gradle Plugin to `v3.1.2`...

**And after updating the Android Gradle Plugin to `v3.1.3`, the installation succeed.**

Also, add this line in your `gradle.properties` may helps too:

```
android.enableD8=false
```

Maybe a bug of Android Gradle Plugin `v3.1.2` with [D8](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#D8)?

Answer (score 0):

Update your android Gradle build tools to 3.1.3 (or higher to fix) the issue with android.enableD8 enabled an no other issues.

```
"com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4"
```